# Where do you find the usage of values() in kotlin doc?

Tags: function, kotlin

I've been googling for values() for some time now but its usage is not mentioned anywhere.

```
class Ticket(
        val name: String,
        val seat: Seat = Coach
        ) {
    enum class Seat {
       Coach,
       Premium,
       Business,
       First
    }

fun upgrade(): Ticket {

   val newSeat = values()[
       (seat.ordinal + 1)
       .coerceAtMost(First.ordinal)
    ]
    return Ticket(name, newSeat)
}
```

I'd never seen this form: values()[] anywhere until now. Could you explain it?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is there an `import Ticket.Seat.values` or `import Ticket.Seat.*` somewhere in your file? Otherwise your code won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is specified in the [Kotlin Language Specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#enum-class-declaration) that:

> In addition to these, every enum class type `E` has the following static member functions declared implicitly:
>
> ```
> public final static fun values(): kotlin.Array<E>
> ```
>
> returning an array of all possible enum values in the order they are declared. Every invocation of this function returns a new array to disallow changing its contents.

Since in the line `val seat: Seat = Coach`, you are able to refer to `Coach` without saying `Seat.Coach`, I'll assume that you have imported `Ticket.Seat.*` in your file.

In that case, the `values()` call in your code is calling `Seat.values()`. You don't need the `Seat.` prefix because it is already imported.

The `[]` syntax after `values()` is simply accessing an element of the array, but rather than using a simple constant number like `1` or `2`, it uses the more complicated expression:

```
(seat.ordinal + 1).coerceAtMost(First.ordinal)
```

If what I assumed wasn't true, then your code wouldn't compile, or `values` is some other function that you didn't include in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. The book I'm reading doesn't explain it and kotlinglangue.org is of no help either. It gave me this: EnumClass.values(): Array<EnumClass>.

Comment: So does your code actually have `import Ticket.Seat.*` somewhere? If so, please edit your question so it's a better question. @ntos